# First four free - changing product pricing based on cart quantity in Commerce using Rules

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

**Brief:**

- Product with SKU "sample" has a unit price of £0.00
- Once quantity > 4, product unit price is £2.50
- First four remain free. E.g if five in cart = (4 x £0.00) + (1 x £2.50).

Currently I have the first two requirements working, I can change the price of a particular product once there are more than 4 items, my current problem is that because the unit price changes, it counts for the four "free". So currently 5 samples bill at £12.50, instead of £2.50.

You can see my rules set up here:
[image: rules problem]

The easiest solution would be to apply a discount of £10.00 to the cart, but I can only see options to alter a unit price of a line item, rather than applying a discount to the order.

How should I do this?

**Possible solution avenue**

I added a second action "Add line item to cart" and created a product with value of -£10.00. The problem here is that when the quantity is reduced to 4 or below, the line item remains. I cannot see a rule option to then remove that line item.

Comment: I would suggest you create a custom Rule action for your use case.

Comment: What you are trying to do is really hard. Question: is 5 the maximum quantity? If it is that makes things easier. If it isn't, that makes this a very hard problem.

Comment: Create a custom rule action. It's going to be simplest way.

Comment: If you're willing to implement a hook from the Commerce API you could use a hook like [`hook_commerce_product_calculate_sell_price_line_item_alter()`](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites%21all%21modules%21commerce%21modules%21product_pricing%21commerce_product_pricing.api.php/function/hook_commerce_product_calculate_sell_price_line_item_alter/DC).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom rules condition for line item which will check next:

- if the amount of items in cart is more than 4
- if the current line item position is greater that 4 (load cart, sort cart line items by created date)

Use the custom condition in pricing rules for line item.